# Passing response from multiple XMLHttpRequests to div

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

I am querying a PostGIS database based on where a user clicks on a google map.  I am then parsing the JSON response into a googleMaps infoWindow.  This has been working great but I'd now like to query multiple urls and use those responses to fill in the infoWindow.  Below is an example of the functions I've used that work great.  Note: please disregard the url provided as I just made it up for this example.

```
var clickLoc;

function queryAct(event){
clickLoc=event.latLng;  
var clickLat=clickLoc.lat();
var clickLng=clickLoc.lng();
var loUrl = 'http://www.myspatialdataset.com/sql/?q=select%20ownercateg%20from%20stew_owners%20where%20ST_Intersects%28the_geom,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28'+clickLng+'%20'+clickLat+'%29%27,4326%29%29';  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.onreadystatechange = clickResponse;
  try {
    req.open("GET", loUrl, true);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  req.send(null);
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
  req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  if (req) {
    req.onreadystatechange = clickResponse;
    req.open("GET", loUrl, true);
    req.send();
  }
}
```

}

```
function clickResponse(){                               
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete
      if (req.status == 200) { // OK response                     
          var clickPingBack = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
          var loResponse = clickPingBack;
          if (loResponse.rows.length>0)
          {
            var loResponseParsed=loResponse.rows[0].ownercateg;
            fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed);
          }
          else
          {
              var loResponseParsed=' other';
              fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed);                                                                      
          }         
      }
}
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed){ 
infowindow.setContent(loResponseParsed);
infowindow.setPosition(clickLoc);
infowindow.open(map);   
}
```

How could I now do this for multiple url requests and pass those responses to the same, fillWithClicked function that fills in the infoWindow?

The code below is obviously wrong but may better explain what I am trying to do i.e. multiple URLS and filling the infoWindow with the response from two url requests.  This sometimes works but is totally wrong

```
var clickLoc;

function distQueryAct(event){
clickLoc=event.latLng;  
var clickLat=clickLoc.lat();
var clickLng=clickLoc.lng();
var distUrl = 'http://www.myspatialdataset.com/sql/?q=select%20district%20from%20mt_elk%20where%20ST_Intersects%28the_geom,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28'+clickLng+'%20'+clickLat+'%29%27,4326%29%29';  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
  distReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  distReq.onreadystatechange = loQueryAct(clickLoc);
  try {
    distReq.open("GET", distUrl, true);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  distReq.send(null);
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
  distReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  if (distReq) {
    distReq.onreadystatechange = loQueryAct(clickLoc);
    distReq.open("GET", distUrl, true);
    distReq.send();
  }
}
}

function loQueryAct(clickLoc){
var clickLat=clickLoc.lat();
var clickLng=clickLoc.lng();
var loUrl = 'http://www.myspatialdataset.com/sql/?q=select%20ownercateg%20from%20stew_owners%20where%20ST_Intersects%28the_geom,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28'+clickLng+'%20'+clickLat+'%29%27,4326%29%29';  
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers
  loReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  loReq.onreadystatechange = distClickResponse;
  try {
    loReq.open("GET", loUrl, true);
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
  loReq.send(null);
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
  loReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  if (loReq) {
    loReq.onreadystatechange = distClickResponse;
    loReq.open("GET", loUrl, true);
    loReq.send();
  }
}
}

function distClickResponse(){                               
    if (distReq.readyState == 4 && loReq.readyState == 4) { // Complete
      if (distReq.status == 200 && loReq.status == 200) { // OK response                      
          var distPingBack = JSON.parse(distReq.responseText);
          var distResponse = distPingBack;
          var loPingBack = JSON.parse(loReq.responseText);
          var loResponse = loPingBack;
          if (distResponse.rows.length>0)
          {
            var distResponseParsed=distResponse.rows[0].district;
          }
          else
          {
              var distResponseParsed=' other';
          } 
           if (loResponse.rows.length>0)
          {
            var loResponseParsed=loResponse.rows[0].ownercateg;             
          }
          else
          {
              var loResponseParsed=' other';                                                      
          }           
      }
      distFillWithClicked(loResponseParsed,distResponseParsed);                           
}
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function distFillWithClicked(distResponseParsed,loResponseParsed){  
infowindow.setContent(distResponseParsed+loResponseParsed);
infowindow.setPosition(clickLoc);
infowindow.open(map);   
}
```

Comment: Does the information from the multiple calls need to be correlated? Or can you go with something simple like adding child divs, one per source?

Comment: What do you mean by the information being correlated?  The responses will be different and do not have to be related in any way.  I will actually be pushing the JSON responses into a google maps info window.  To keep the question simple I just called it a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Using getJSON instead of XMLHttpRequest was the key.  I know this could be cleaner but it does work.

```
var clickLoc;

function queryAct(event){
clickLoc=event.latLng;  
var clickLat=clickLoc.lat();
var clickLng=clickLoc.lng();    
var toFillArray=Array();
var loUrl='http://www.mypostgis.com/sql/?q=select%20ownercateg%20from%20stew_owners%20where%20ST_Intersects%28the_geom,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28'+clickLng+'%20'+clickLat+'%29%27,4326%29%29'; 
var distUrl='http://www.mypostgis.com/sql/?q=select%20district%20from%20mt_elk%20where%20ST_Intersects%28the_geom,%20ST_GeomFromText%28%27POINT%28'+clickLng+'%20'+clickLat+'%29%27,4326%29%29';   
$.getJSON(loUrl,function(tmpLoDat){     
    if (tmpLoDat.rows.length>0)
    {
        var tempCat=tmpLoDat.rows[0].ownercateg;        
        toFillArray.push(tempCat);
    }
    else
    {
        var tempCat='other';
        toFillArray.push(tempCat);  
    }       
    otherFunction(toFillArray,distUrl);
    })                  
}

function otherFunction(toFillArray,distUrl){
$.getJSON(distUrl,function(tmpDistDat){
    if (tmpDistDat.rows.length>0)
    {
        var tempDist=tmpDistDat.rows[0].district;
        toFillArray.push(tempDist);
    }
    else
    {
        var tempDist='Other';
        toFillArray.push(tempDist);
    }
    fillWithClicked(toFillArray);
    })      
}



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function fillWithClicked(toFillArray){ 
infowindow.setContent(toFillArray[0]+toFillArray[1]);
infowindow.setPosition(clickLoc);
infowindow.open(map);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to grow your element, let's try something like that :

```
function fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed){ 
document.getElementById("regulations").innerHTML += loResponseParsed;
}
```

If the calls of your function are not in the same page, you'll need to use a cache file and a user_id (session id, cookie id or IP adress...):

```
// js & jquery for example
function fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed,user_id)
{ 
    $.post('cachecreate.php',{content:loResponseParsed,user_id:user_id},
      function() 
      {
        $.get('cachefile_'+user_id+'.html', 
          function(data)
          {
            document.getElementById("regulations").innerHTML=data;
          });
      });
}

// cachecreate.php for example
<?php
$cache = "cachefile_".$_POST['user_id'].".html";
ob_start();
if(file_exists($cache))
{
  include($cache);//or readfile(); i forgot...
  echo "<hr/>".$_POST['content'];// Strip <hr/> for JSON
}
else
{
  echo $_POST['content'];
}
$page_content=ob_get_contents();// if JSON needed : json_encode($page_content);
ob_end_clean();
file_put_contents($cache, $page_content);// PHP 5+ function
?>
```

I hope that it may help you, or bring you to the solution.

**EDIT regarding your new details**

Try something like this (I lighten your code...).
With this you can add as multiple urls as you want.

```
var clickLoc;

function queryAct(event)
{
    clickLoc=event.latLng;  
    var clickLat=clickLoc.lat();
    var clickLng=clickLoc.lng();
    var url=Array(); 
    var data=null;
    url['loUrl'] ="url1"; 
    url['distUrl'] ="url2"; 
    url['otherUrl'] ="urlx"; 
    for(page in url)
    {
        data+=getJSON(page);
    }
    fillWithClicked(data);
}

function getJSON(url)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {req = new XMLHttpRequest();}// Non-IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}// IE
    if(req) 
    {     
      req.open("GET", url, true);
      req.send(null);
      req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState == 4) 
        {
          if (req.status == 200) 
          { // OK response                     
              var clickPingBack = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
              var loResponse = clickPingBack;
              if (loResponse.rows.length>0)
              {
                var loResponseParsed=loResponse.rows[0].ownercateg;
              }
              else
              {
                  var loResponseParsed=' other';                                            
              }
              return loResponseParsed;         
          }
        }
      }
    }
}

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

function fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed)
{ 
    infowindow.setContent(loResponseParsed);
    infowindow.setPosition(clickLoc);
    infowindow.open(map);   
}
```

**EDIT -> External domain files**

httpRequest doesn't work with files in another domain.
You can use one of those solutions, I may use the second for me.

PHP Solution

```
// In your js file, change the urls like this
url['url_x'] ='myphppage.php?url=url_x_to_parse';

// myphpage.php script that displays the content of the external file
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url'])) {
    header("Content-type: text/json");
    echo file_get_contents(urldecode($_GET['url']));
}
?>
```

JQUERY solution (better one)

// change the name of getJSON function cause jquery uses the same name...

```
  function getURLcontent(url)
  {
     $.get(url,function(data){
          var clickPingBack = JSON.parse(data.responseText); 
          var loResponse = clickPingBack;
          loResponse=data;
          if (loResponse.rows.length>0)
          {
            var loResponseParsed=loResponse.rows[0].ownercateg;
          }
          else
          {
              var loResponseParsed=' other';                                            
          }
          return loResponseParsed;         
      });
  }
```

- download jquery library http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
- include jquery plugin in the head of your page with `<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I will not be growing the content of my div, just changing it with content from two synchronous XMLHttpRequests. The calls to my function are in the same page.  Also, querying my PostGIS does not require a user_id or session_id.

Comment: Sorry but your question is really not clear, please detail exactly what you want and what you mean with "query multiple urls". Explain with a use case ! Something like : 1.user click a map 2.the system gets json... 3.the system displays... More details about the features.

Comment: "How could I now do this for multiple url requests and pass those responses to the same, fillWithClicked function that fills in the div?"
function fillWithClicked(loResponseParsed){ 
document.getElementById("regulations").innerHTML += loResponseParsed;
} Is the right answer to your question ! Try it ! If it is not this, your question is not well formed...

Comment: Valky, I added some additional code that may better illustrate what I am trying to do.  (1) user clicks map which generates a lat/lng and fires the function that will run the XMLHttpRequests.  (2) Two URLs are created using the LatLng from the user's click.  (3)These urls are then queried which returns JSON which is in turn put into the divs.

Comment: Thanks Valky..  I am getting a couple errors after adding my urls.  (1) when i run the code with "var url=null" I get an error of "url is null".  I changed "var url=null" to "var url=new Array();) and it does not seem to throw an error.  The second error I receive is "[08:34:07.801] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Access to restricted URI denied"  code: "1012" nsresult: "0x805303f4 (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)"  location: "file:///D:/GIS/projects/index.html Line: 148"]".  In this case, line 148 is "req.send(null);".  Any ideas what might be causing these errors?

Comment: Sorry, I edit it, it was : var url=Array();
For the next error, I think that it could be a cotes problem, make an alert of the urls in the "for in" to see if the url are ok

Comment: Yes, httpRequest only works with files from the same domain/server.
I add 2 solutions in my answer to make it work.

Comment: Valky..  The getJSON function does not appear to be executing past the point of   $.getJSON(url,function(data){

Comment: Perhaps the external files are not in real JSON format, so use :  $.get(url,function(data){
          var clickPingBack = JSON.parse(data.responseText); 
          var loResponse = clickPingBack;
          loResponse=data;

Comment: No, try : $.get instead of $.getJSON

Comment: var data=Array(); data is not an array. Put data=null;
You have an url problem also : GET http://www.gagecartographics.com/test/loUrl 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.gagecartographics.com/test/distUrl 404 (Not Found)
And is it you who put my answer -1 notation ?

Comment: Change the name of this var, perhaps stil use in your main.js page. Or set data='';